# Transformation of series, proving an equality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

An exercise asks to find all values of $x \in \Re$ for  which the following equality holds true:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha+n}x^n = \frac{1}{\alpha(1+x)}\left[1+\frac1{\alpha+1}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)+\frac{1\cdot2}{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^2+\dots\right]$$ where $\alpha$ is a real number clearly different from $0, -1, -2, \dots$
First each expression makes sense only if it is finite, so we restrict ourselves to the domain $-1/2 \le x \le 1$, where each series is convergent. Then I noticed that if $x = 1$ or $x = -1/2$ then the equality holds, for it just follows from Euler transformation of convergent series (see second type of Euler Transform for details https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html). I was wondering if this equality is valid for other values of $x$ but could not find an answer. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality holds for $-1/2<x\leqslant 1$ and $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Z}_{\leqslant 0}$, and for $x=-1/2$ and $\alpha>0$.

It is sufficient to show it for $\alpha>0$ (since both sides satisfy $f(x,\alpha)+xf(x,\alpha+1)=1/\alpha$, which allows to show it for $\alpha>-n$ using induction on $n$) and $-1/2<x<1$ (then the convergence at the boundary values of $x$ *when it holds*, and [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), do the rest). Now
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n+\alpha}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x)^n\int_0^1 y^{n+\alpha-1}\,dy
=\int_0^1\frac{y^{\alpha-1}\,dy}{1+xy}
\\&=\frac{1}{1+x}\int_0^1\frac{(1-z)^{\alpha-1}\,dz}{1-xz/(1+x)}\qquad\color{gray}{[y=1-z]}
\\&=\frac{1}{1+x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^n\int_0^1 z^n(1-z)^{\alpha-1}\,dz,
\end{align*}
and the [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is $\mathrm{B}(n+1,\alpha)=\displaystyle\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}=\frac{n!}{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+n)}$.

Comment: I don't really understand why Abel's theorem helps to show it for $-1/2<x<1$. Also what is $f$?

Comment: Abel's theorem helps to handle $x=-1/2$ and $x=1$ (already done by you, just a different reason). $f$ is either side of the equality being proven.

Comment: Ok! Your proof works only for $\alpha > 0$ (to explain the assumption)? Why $x=-1/2$ only for $\alpha>0$?

Comment: Because if $x=-1/2$ and $\alpha<0$ the series on the RHS diverges (its term doesn't tend to $0$).

Comment: Ok it's true that in that case the general term doesn't go to 0. But do we really need the equality with $f$? If so why? I still have to study the exchange of a sum with integral, so maybe this is why?

Comment: I guess that the last integral holds only if $\alpha>0$?

Comment: The logic is as follows. We handle $\alpha>0$ "the integrals way" (we can't use it for $\alpha<0$ since we get divergent integrals). Now, if $L(x,\alpha)$ is the LHS, and $R(x,\alpha)$ is the RHS, then both $L(x,\alpha)+xL(x,\alpha+1)=1/\alpha$ and $R(x,\alpha)+xR(x,\alpha+1)=1/\alpha$. Thus, $L(x,\alpha+1)=R(x,\alpha+1)$ **implies** $L(x,\alpha)=R(x,\alpha)$, so if our equality holds for $\alpha>0$, then it holds for $\alpha>-1$ (and then it does for $\alpha>-2$, etc.).

Comment: (This is just what's written *compactly* in the answer.)

Comment: Thank you very much, now I follow you!!

Comment: And finally, $R(x,\alpha)+xR(x,\alpha+1)=1/\alpha$ is not entirely trivial to verify (in case you'll try it yourself), but it becomes easy after denoting $x/(1+x)=y$ (then $1/(1+x)=1-y$).